# How to access mysql database from android application in order to create login and logout using Java i.e., without php?

Tags: database, android-studio-2.1

I have made the android app for my college. In that I have made the Login Activity page. Also, I have designed one web portal for my college consisting of the details of students such as their name, admission no., roll no, contact no. etc. using Mysql workbench. Now I want to access this Mysql database from my android application in so that I can login into the application using roll no. as the username and contact no. as the password.

I want to do this whole thing using Java and without php.

Answer (score -1):

You may consider developing a **Servlet** to run on a container (e.g. TOMCAT). The Servlet (which is developed in Java) would access the database. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) you have an example of how this is done.

EDIT:

First, you need to add to your app the ability to send HTTP(S) requests. Plenty of examples in the Web.

Second, you need to deploy a Servlet container software product (I suggest TOMCAT).

Third develop a simple Servlet to handle `post` requests and access MySQL (again, plenty of examples in the Web, including some that you can almost copy-paste as-is).

Fourth, create a WAR file of the Servlet and deploy it into your Servlet container (if TOMCAT, under the folder `webapps`).

You will have to fine-tune configurations, but it should be straightforward.

Good luck!!!

Comment: But how will the same be connected to my android app. I have the project in android studio and database in sql workbench.

Comment: Android... It can communicate with the server using TCP/UDP or via Web services hosted in the TOMCAT (i.e. implemented through servlets). My suggestion refers to the second option. So, you can set your TOMCAT to accept HTTP or HTTPS connections (you would need a certificate for the last) and send from your app HTTP(s) requests. Plenty of examples in the Web.

Comment: I don't want to do the connectivity globally. I just want to access the database locally that is through localhost Just as a dummy .

Comment: You are planning to deploy MySQL DB into the mobile?

Comment: FDavidov, I have designed the website for my college and in that there is the database of the students created in mysql workbench. Now I want to login in the app using the fields which are in this database. We can take roll no. as username and the contact as password.

Comment: Look, you don't establish a direct connection from a mobile application and the database (though technically is possible, this is not done for security reasons). You always put something in-between, in my suggestion it would be the Servlet.

Comment: So can you please tell me from where should I actually start. What should be the first step which I should take? Please tell me step by step sir. i wud be very greatful to you.